# Can WCF handle GUIDs?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, guid

I ask because my unit tests which connect to my local dev database have no problem using Guids, but when I use the same methods via my WCF service, it fails with the following exception:

```
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException
```

I've read the WCF converts Guids to strings. My exact scenario is this:

Proxy -> pass object with Guid

Service <- connect to db, insert/retrieve things w/Guid

Service -> pass object with Guid back to proxy

Here is the error when testing the WCF service from the web application:

```
[FaultException`1: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9456095
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
   BusinessServices.NGIT.ServiceContracts.IIssueTrackerService.CreateIssue(CreateIssueRequest request) +0
   NGIT.Proxies.c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IIssueTrackerService s) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\NextGenIssueTracker.Proxies\Proxies\IssueTrackerProxy.cs:25
   NGIT.Proxies.UseServiceFunction.UseService(ChannelFactory`1 channelFactory, Func`2 useService) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\NextGenIssueTracker.Proxies\Helpers\UseServiceFunction.cs:26
   NGIT.Proxies.IssueTrackerProxy.CreateIssue(CreateIssueRequest request) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\NextGenIssueTracker.Proxies\Proxies\IssueTrackerProxy.cs:25
   NGIT.Test.ClientProxy.Default.createIssueButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\NGIT.Test.ClientProxy\Default.aspx.cs:36
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

And here is the inner exception from Trace Viewer:

```
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException, System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateFunctionObjectResult[TElement](EntityCommand entityCommand, EntitySet entitySet, EdmType edmType, MergeOption mergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
at NGIT.Data.UserIssueEntities.CreateIssue(String issueTitle, String nextGenUserId, Nullable`1 guid) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\NextGenIssueTracker.Data\UserIssueObjectGenerator.cs:line 305
at Liberty.DataAccess.NGIT.SqlUserIssueRepository.AddIssue(User user, Issue issue) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\DataAccess.NextGenIssueTracker\Repositories\SqlUserIssueRepository.cs:line 51
at BusinessServices.NGIT.ServiceImplementations.IssueTrackerService.CreateIssue(CreateIssueRequest request) in D:\NextGenIssueTracker\branches\2011Updates\BusinessServices.NextGenIssueTracker\ServiceImplementations\IssueTrackerService.cs:line 59
at SyncInvokeCreateIssue(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: The exception type implies this is a data-related exception. Can you post the full exception (message, type + stack trace)?

Comment: I'm not sure that the GUID data type is interoperable.  Have you tried just substituting a string?

Comment: And what's the inner exception of the `EntityCommandExecutionException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/gg413252#G) (.NET GUID -> Java String)

Of course, what is the actual issue can not be determined with just what you posted.

Comment: Keep it bookmarked, because if you plan on exposing your service to Java clients its very handy to know what they should expect and what issues you'll run into.

Answer (score 1):

I've used WCF with GUID-based entities without any issues. I don't think that's your problem here, or anything to do with WCF for that matter. This sounds more like an issue at your database level:

***[EntityCommandExecutionException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitycommandexecutionexception.aspx)*** 
Represents errors that occur when the underlying storage provider could not execute the specified command. This exception usually wraps a provider-specific exception.